# Exception in thread "main" 0: No such file or directory: hadoop map reduce

Tags: windows, eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run the basic word count job using map reduce. The source code is available on official website.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;


public class TestDriver {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      BasicConfigurator.configure();
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(TestDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

my console output is:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93 class loader.
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.properties] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
log4j: Could not find resource: [null].
1 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory  - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginSuccess with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(always=false, sampleName=Ops, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of successful kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
39 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory  - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.loginFailure with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(always=false, sampleName=Ops, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[Rate of failed kerberos logins and latency (milliseconds)], valueName=Time)
40 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory  - field org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableRate org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.getGroups with annotation @org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.annotation.Metric(always=false, sampleName=Ops, about=, type=DEFAULT, value=[GetGroups], valueName=Time)
46 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl  - UgiMetrics, User and group related metrics
416 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosName  - Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
429 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups  -  Creating new Groups object
439 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Trying to load the custom-built native-hadoop library...
449 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  - Loaded the native-hadoop library
451 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping  - Using JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping for Group resolution
451 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback  - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping
545 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups  - Group mapping impl=org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback; cacheTimeout=300000; warningDeltaMs=5000
558 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - hadoop login
560 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - hadoop login commit
577 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - using local user:NTUserPrincipal: Arunaabh
577 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - Using user: "NTUserPrincipal: Arunaabh" with name Arunaabh
578 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - User entry: "Arunaabh"
579 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - UGI loginUser:Arunaabh (auth:SIMPLE)
862 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:Arunaabh (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.connect(Job.java:1255)
878 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster  - Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider
879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster  - Cannot pick org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider as the ClientProtocolProvider - returned null protocol
884 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster  - Trying ClientProtocolProvider : org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider
913 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation  - session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
916 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics.jvm.JvmMetrics  - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
1000 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster  - Picked org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalClientProtocolProvider as the ClientProtocolProvider
1002 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:Arunaabh (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Cluster.getFileSystem(Cluster.java:162)
1014 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:Arunaabh (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
1044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Configuring job job_local545640952_0001 with file:/tmp/hadoop-Arunaabh/mapred/staging/Arunaabh545640952/.staging/job_local545640952_0001 as the submit dir
1044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - adding the following namenodes' delegation tokens:[file:///]
2292 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader  - Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
2293 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader  - default FileSystem: file:///
2392 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO  - Initialized cache for IDs to User/Group mapping with a  cache timeout of 14400 seconds.
2400 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter  - Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-Arunaabh/mapred/staging/Arunaabh545640952/.staging/job_local545640952_0001
2401 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedActionException as:Arunaabh (auth:SIMPLE) cause:0: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" 0: No such file or directory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:502)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:600)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
    at TestDriver.main(TestDriver.java:62)
```

My configurations for single node cluster is from official website:
    https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows

I have passed the following as arguments:

```
C:\Users\Arunaabh\workspace\TestHadoop\hadooptest.txt  
C:\Users\Arunaabh\workspace\TestHadoop\output
```

The error does not seem to be a java input or io exception. Additionally my yarn and namenode and datanodes are working properly.

I am running hadoop on WINDOWS please do not post linux answers.

Answer (score 0):

you have passed local file system's input and output file as parameter to mapreduced job

```
C:\Users\Arunaabh\workspace\TestHadoop\hadooptest.txt  
C:\Users\Arunaabh\workspace\TestHadoop\output
```

You need to provide input and output file parameter from hdfs file system

Comment: input path :hdfs://0.0.0.0:19000/input/hadooptest.txt Output path: /output gives the same result.